# How to get fileupload control in gridview using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, file-upload

Hi I have a file upload in my footer in my gridview, i want to get it in javascript. The following code gets me the fileupload but using vb,

```
Dim fileuploadftrCardImage As FileUpload = DirectCast(gvCardsProvider.FooterRow.FindControl("fileuploadftrCardImage"), FileUpload)
```

I want to take it using javascript

the following doesn't work since the fileupload is in my gridview

```
var file = document.querySelector('#<%=fileuploadftrCardImage.ClientID %>').files[0];
```

Anyways is there any way i can get it?

Comment: Does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20471903/1191903 (it is for a TextBox but the principle is the same)

Comment: no, it gives me the following error Error 4 'FileUpload' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.